# Were there any other names that were plays on words in The Hunger Games?

Tags: the-hunger-games

To quote wikipedia:

> Katniss' name comes from a plant that is more commonly known as
>   Sagittaria, which is a tuber plant usually found in water.[4] The root
>   of this plant can be eaten, as Katniss does in the book. Her father
>   once said: "As long as you can find yourself, you'll never starve."
>   This name also means "belonging to an arrow" in Latin, which may have
>   a connection with Katniss's skill with a bow and arrow. The plant also
>   shares its name with a constellation in the Zodiac called Sagittarius,
>   or "The Archer", which may also reference Katniss's skills in archery.

Peeta is a baker with a name that sounds very much like "Pita bread", depending on how you pronounce it. Primrose (Prim) is also a name of a plant.

Are there any other names that are "puns" or also objects that are related to the character in question?

Comment: The leaf of the Sagittaria plant is shaped like an arrowhead hence the connection.

Comment: Naming children, especially females, after plants native to one's area is not exactly an uncommon practice. It's been done throughout history.

Answer (score 13):

Would you consider Panem to be a play on words, considering bread is an important part of the story?  (Peeta, different loaves representing different Areas, etc.)  As well as Panem et Circenses being the theme.

Comment: can you please explain the play on words for us non-native English speakers?

Comment: @MateuszL Latin, as it happens: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bread_and_circuses

Answer (score 11):

I think Snow was named as a reference to a cold-blooded ruler, while Coin's name indicated that she was "a different side of the same coin"; in essence, no different than Snow.

Answer (score 5):

Whilst not puns, many of the characters have names used in Shakespeare's play:

- Coriolanus
- Cinna
- Enobarbia (from Ahenobarbus)
- Caesar
- Portia
- Flavius

> Also the two main characters are referred in the books as "the star crossed lovers" as in Romeo and Juliet; the use of poison in the play and in book 1 has some parallels

Answer (score 1):

**Snow**
In *The Ballad of Songbirds and Snakes* it is revealed that the Snow family moto is "Snow always lands on top". This signifies how their family are both survivors as well as very cunning and resourceful; able to make the best out of any situation.

**Trinket**
Effie Trinket was into jewellery and similar nic-nacs. She was always adorned with 'trinkets'.

Also, she gave each of her team a golden token or 'trinket', to symbolise them being a team!

**Thresh**
Thresh was the male tribute from the same district as Rue - they were the gardeners and tended to the trees/crops. See: [threshing](https://www.google.com/search?q=threshing). Not sure if related, but sounds like a pun to me.

**Plutarch**
Plutarch was a Greek philosopher and according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plutarch), he was "known for his Parallel Lives" (series of books). Sound familiar?

**Highbottom**
Dean Casca Highbottom spent much of his adult life under the intoxication of 'morphling'. He was even called Dean "High-as-a-kite-Bottom"

Answer (score 0):

This  [article](https://slate.com/culture/2014/11/hunger-games-names-meanings-explanations-for-katniss-everdeen-peeta-mellark-alma-cressida-and-more.html) analyzes many of the names in the book, such as Flickerman, Beetee, and more:

Flickerman

> His last name, Flickerman, evokes both the bright (but flickering?)
> lights of the big city and the filming of the games (a movie is also
> a flick). In the books he wears a suit decorated with light bulbs.

Beetee

> The name of Beetee, a tribute at the 75th Hunger Games and the tech
> genius behind many of the rebellion’s coolest moves—such as hijacking
> the Capitol’s television feed—sounds out the first two letters of BTU,
> a unit used to measure energy. Sound like a stretch? Well, Beetee
> teamed up with Wiress to make up “nuts and volts,” volts, of course,
> being a measurement of electricity.