# Is Peeta's name a reference to pita bread?

Tags: the-hunger-games

Related to, but not a duplicate, of [Were there any other names that were plays on words in The Hunger Games?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8999/were-there-any-other-names-that-were-plays-on-words-in-the-hunger-games) as far as i can tell.

Peeta is the son of the baker. His name sounds almost exactly like "pita", a kind of bread.

Is there any **canonical** evidence that this is an intentional pun?

Comment: Lets not forget People for Ethical Treatment of Animals, which in a way also works for this character. But no matter which way you look at it, I am certain Peeta is an Aptronym.

Answer (score 10):

To my knowledge, Suzanne Collins has never definitively stated this either way.

However, the fan consensus is that Peeta's name is a reference to the fact that he comes from a family of bakers. In addition to the homonym, Peeta's name may also be a reference to his following of another - as did Peter, the apostle.

[Slate explains](http://www.slate.com/blogs/browbeat/2014/11/19/hunger_games_names_meanings_explanations_for_katniss_everdeen_peeta_mellark.html)

> Peeta Mellark (Josh Hutcherson: Katniss’ fellow District 12 tribute comes from a family of bread bakers, and his name is an alternate—or dystopic, if you will—spelling of pita. The humble Peeta stands in contrast to the grandiose Panem, which, as noted above, is Latin for bread. Commenters have also pointed out that Peeta is very similar to Peter—and while Hunger names are not generally Biblical, Peeta is, like that apostle, the closest friend to the savior (Katniss), and does everything he can for her.

Answer (score 2):

Within the book canon, no. There's no evidence that it's a pun by his parent although in fairness his father is a baker and you'd think he would have spotted it.

---

Out of universe, it was almost certainly intended as a small joke. According to [Entertainment Weekly](http://www.ew.com/ew/quiz/0,,20419951_20874592,00.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A%20entertainmentweekly%2Flatest%20%28Entertainment%20Weekly%3A%20%20Today%27s%20Latest%29#30253857), Suzanne Collins stated that Katniss and Pita's son and daughter would be named Willow (another kind of medicinal plant) and Rye (another kind of bread) however I've been unable to find a canonical source for this assertion.

Comment: If you provide a link to that tweet, that would be good enough for me.

Comment: @Scimonster - I can't find one, which would strongly suggest that it's either been deleted or fabricated.

Answer (score 0):

I am basing my answer off of the book. Peeta was born into baking. (Pita Bread) This bread is pronounced the same. Also in the first book, The Hunger Games, Peeta gives burnt bread to Katniss when she is starving because of the fact that her father had just died. In conclusion, I think this was intentional being the baker's son, having a type of bread as a name, and his experience with Katniss.

Answer (score 0):

My girlfriend is reading a book about body medicine:
[http://www.amazon.com/Perfect-Health-Complete-Revised-Updated/dp/0609806947](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0609806947)

In this "science", there are elements like water, fire, air and earth which are linked to names.

And fire is linked to "Pitta".

Considering that the title of the book is Hunger Games: Catching fire, it could be a possible origin of the name of the boy.

Who knows what the author read...